# How do I use equal sign on chfn command?

Tags: linux, command-line, command

I tried chfn to change the umask value of a user as follows

```
sudo chfn -o umask=022 username
```

But I have this error

```
chfn: Office: '=' is not allowed
```

I also tried a failed attempt to escape the = sign as follows

```
sudo chfn -o umask\=022 username
sudo chfn -o "umask=022 username"
```

How can I use or escape the equal sign with this command?

Thx

Comment: What distro are you using? I'm able to set the GECOS field to something with an `=` without an issue. Judging by the error message, it's trying to set a value for `Office`, which is not what `-o` is used for in my version of `chfn` (ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @rustyshackleford its CentOS Linux 7 (Core). And yes I am trying to set value for office.

Comment: @Laxman Are you trying to change the `umask` or the office number? If you want to change the office number then the command is `sudo chfn -o 123 username` where `123` would be whatever office number you want. The default umask in `Centos 7` is already `002` as one can see with `grep umask /etc/profile` or `grep umask /etc/bashrc`.

Comment: @NasirRiley I am trying to change the umask for a particular user.

Comment: @NasirRileym in that case, how do I change the umask for a particular user other than chfn command ? thx

Comment: @Laxman ikkachu's answer will work but the user can always change it to whatever they want and undo what you did by editing their `.bash_profile`or `.bashrc` and placing a `umask` line inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chfn` changes the information in the fourth field  of `/etc/passwd` (or equivalent). Most of the data there is only used for display purposes, and it's even called the "user name or comment field" in the [`passwd(5)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5@@shadow-utils.html).

Debian's [man page for `chfn(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chfn.1@@shadow-utils.html) however mentions that part of it is used for "accounting information". Apparently [`pam_umask.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_umask.8.html) also reads it, which is what I suppose you want. The man page also mentions the prohibition on the equal sign:

> These fields must not contain any colons. Except for the *other* field, they should not contain any comma or equal sign.
>
> `-o, --other OTHER`
> Change the user's other GECOS information. This field is used to store accounting information used by other applications, and can be changed only by a superuser.

It seems that the `chfn` on your CentOS follows a different syntax, and doesn't provide a way to change the "other" part. Testing on Debian, the result of `chfn -o 'umask=022' username` is:

```
username:x:1000:1000:Full name,,,,umask=022:/home/username:/bin/bash
```

So, a workaround for the lack of functionality in `chfn` would be edit the file manually (with `vipw`), and add the `umask=022` after the fourth comma in the comment field.

Comment: yup, you are correct. I check the vipw, the entry is as follows: `username:x:1000:1000:,umask:/home/username:/bin/bash` There is no =022

Comment: @Laxman, `vipw` just launches an editor (as if you started `$VISUAL /etc/passwd`), so just add the commas and the `umask=...` by hand. Use something like `VISUAL=nano vipw` if it insists on running `vi` and you don't happen to be familiar with it. `vipw` should double-check the line for you so you can't mess it up, but it's still probably better to test logins before exiting the root shell.

Comment: (And yes, I said "root shell". run `sudo -s` first so that you don't get locked out.)

Comment: I used vi editor instead by taking a backup, and added the umask manually, but it does not seems to work. or at-least change the umask for the user. The line now reads as `username:x:1000:1000:,umask=0022:/home/username:/bin/bash`

Comment: @Laxman, "after the fourth comma". It's a comma-separated field where the first part is the user's full name, the rest are the others.

Comment: yup updated the umask after the fourth comma but not effect `username:x:1000:1000:Fullname,,,,umask=022:/home/username:/bin/bash` :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78465/discussion-between-laxman-and-ilkkachu).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this man page: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-chfn/

The `-o` option is to set an office room number, so I think it's erroring because `=` isn't a valid number.

Interestingly, on ubuntu 16.04 the `-o` option is used to set the GECOS field in `/etc/passwd`, which is what you are trying to do, rather than setting an office number.

Comment: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/login-utils/ch-common.c

Comment: I want to change the default file + folder permissions to 644 & 755 for a particular user. The current umask value is 002, so I need it to change to 022. Thats why I am trying to change the umask using chfn but the equal sign caused the problem...

Comment: @Laxman I have not seen this way of setting umask before. Do you have more information? The only thing (that I found) on the internet that suggests that this is a proper way is https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/set-umask-for-another-user and I suspect that it is the reason why you are asking about this.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve the same by modifying the bashrc

```
vi ~/.bashrc
...
# User specific aliases and functions
umask 022
```

Thx